# Replace failing HDD with SSD in Ubuntu while avoiding reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

I run vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 as my daily driver on a Lenovo ThinkPad P72. There are 2 drives in it, 1 Intel M.2 SSD where `/` is mounted and a Seagate 1 TB HDD where `/home` is mounted. Partitions are not encrypted.

Recently, I started to see SMART reporting bad sectors on the Seagate drive and I was forced to do a `fsck` on it during a reboot. I bought a Samsung 860 EVO 1 TB SSD drive to replace the Seagate drive. I haven't done the swap of drives yet ... Is there a straight forward way to do this without having to reinstall the OS?  Can I possibly clone the Seagate drive into the Samsung with a tool, replace and reboot?

I assume this is doable but that the devil is in the little details (such as partition UUIDs).

Comment: First thing, make a disk image before the HDD is unusable... then clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the geometry of the HDD is not larger then the SSD (and it is likely they are the same) you should be able to use ddrescue to bit copy the HDD to the SSD. It is likely this will work for you if the HDD is not too far gone.

You should boot of a usb disk to do the ddrescue so the source filesystem is not otherwise in use. Make sure you get the drive identifiers the right way round and use /dev/sdX not sdX1